# Running Oracle SQL job in parallel from Python

Tags: python, oracle, parallel-processing, cx-oracle

I have setup my cx_Oracle connection as follows:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("ALTER SESSION SET \"_PARALLEL_CLUSTER_CACHE_POLICY\" =ADAPTIVE")
```

followed by

```
df_plcy_trm = pd.read_sql_query(query_plcy_trm, conn)
```

However, the query does not seem to be running in parallel.
The query runs much faster natively in Oracle than through cx_Oracle connection. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively You can execute your query parallelly using the `PARALLEL` Hint as follows.

```
query_plcy_trm = """SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */ ename, dname FROM emp e, dept d WHERE e.deptno=d.deptno""";

df_plcy_trm = pd.read_sql_query(query_plcy_trm, conn)
```